# Where do I put in a custom rails method with paramaters and math?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a custom method I made in ruby that I'm hoping to put into my rails app.

You can test it out here: https://repl.it/Ezqr/20

```
def time_clock(hour, min)
...
end
```

I also have a rails app with a simple scaffold. The scaffold I ran was

```
rails g scaffold Timeclock hour_in:integer minutes_in:integer
```

I would like to be able to put my custom time_clock method into my rails app and see it in the view. But where does the method go? Or at least how am I supposed to implement it into my rails app? does it go into the controller or the model?...help!

Comment: Are you intending to only use `time_clock` in a view? Where it goes depends on where you want to use it.

Comment: well I want to show the return value thats in the method. The method rounds numbers up or down. It's for the clock my job uses to round hours when people clock in. I want to show a new value in the view.

Comment: have you try it put in an helper and try access a method in your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can this code in you view `xxx.html.erb`

```
<div id="page_wrapper">
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Timeclocks</h1>

  <% @timeclocks.each do |timeclock| %>
    <div class="timeclock_wrapper">
      <p class="date">
        Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(timeclock.created_at) %> Ago
      </p>

        <%= minutes, fin_hour_with_30, fin_hour = min_hour_and_half_hour(timeclock) %>
        <p> You are off at <strong><%= "#{fin_hour}:#{minutes}" %></strong> PM Without A lunch </p>
        <p> You are off at <strong><%= "#{fin_hour_with_30}:#{minutes_with_30}" %></strong> PM With A 30 minute lunch </p>
        <p> You are off at <strong><%= "#{fin_hour.to_i + 1}:#{minutes}" %></strong> PM With A 1 Hour lunch</p>
        <p>Inserted Hour: <strong><%= timeclock.hour_in %></strong></p>
        <% if timeclock.minutes_in < 10 %>
        <p>Final Minutes: 0<%= timeclock.minutes_in %></p>
        <p>Inserted Minutes 0<%= timeclock.minutes_in %></p>
        <% else %>
        <p>Final Minutes: <%= timeclock.minutes_in %></p>
        <p>Inserted Minutes <%= timeclock.minutes_in %></p>
        <% end %>
        <button class="button"> <%= link_to 'Show', timeclock %></button>
        <button class="button"> <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_timeclock_path(timeclock) %></button>
        <button class="button"> <%= link_to 'Destroy', timeclock, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></button>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<br>

<button class="button"><%= link_to 'New Timeclock', new_timeclock_path %></button>
</div>
```

And you can make a helper method, like in `helpers/application.rb`

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def min_hour_and_half_hour(timeclock)
    minutes = timeclock.minutes_in % 60
    fin_hour = (timeclock.hour_in + 8) - 12
    if (57 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 59) || (0 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 2)
    minutes = "00"
    minutes_with_30 = "30"
    fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour
    elsif (3 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 8  )
      minutes = "06"
      minutes_with_30 = "36"
      fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour
    elsif (9 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 14)
      minutes = "12"
      minutes_with_30 = "42"
      fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour
    elsif (15 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 20)
      minutes = "18"
      minutes_with_30 = "48"
      fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour
    elsif (21 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 26 )
      minutes = "24"
      minutes_with_30 = "54"
      fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour
    elsif (27 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 32 )
      minutes = "30"
      fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour + 1
      minutes_with_30 = "00"
      fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour + 1
    elsif (33 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 38)
      minutes = "36"
      minutes_with_30 = "06"
      fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour + 1
    elsif (39 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 44)
      fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour + 1
      minutes = "42"
      minutes_with_30 = "12"
    elsif (45 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 50)
      fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour + 1
      minutes = "48"
      minutes_with_30 = "18"
    elsif (51 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 56)
     fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour + 1
      minutes = "54"  
      minutes_with_30 = "24"
    else
      minutes = min % 60
    end 
    minutes, fin_hour_with_30, fin_hour
  end
end
```

This would be bit clear and neat code.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using this code in my view. Is there a better practice?

```
<div id="page_wrapper">
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Timeclocks</h1>

    <% @timeclocks.each do |timeclock| %>
    <div class="timeclock_wrapper">
        <p class="date">
          Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(timeclock.created_at) %> Ago
        </p>
            <% minutes = timeclock.minutes_in % 60 %>
            <% fin_hour = (timeclock.hour_in + 8) - 12  %>
            <%if (57 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 59) || (0 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 2) %>
              <%minutes = "00" %>
              <%minutes_with_30 = "30" %>
              <%fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour %>
          <%  elsif (3 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 8  ) %>
            <%  minutes = "06" %>
            <%  minutes_with_30 = "36" %>
            <%  fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour %>
          <%  elsif (9 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 14) %>
          <%    minutes = "12" %>
          <%    minutes_with_30 = "42" %>
          <%    fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour %>
          <%  elsif (15 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 20)   %>
          <%    minutes = "18" %>
          <%    minutes_with_30 = "48" %>
          <%    fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour %>
          <%  elsif (21 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 26 )  %>
          <%    minutes = "24" %>
          <%    minutes_with_30 = "54" %>
          <%    fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour %>
          <%  elsif (27 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 32 )  %>
          <%    minutes = "30" %>
          <%    fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour + 1 %>
          <%    minutes_with_30 = "00" %>
          <%    fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour + 1 %>
          <%  elsif (33 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 38)   %>
          <%    minutes = "36"   %>
          <%    minutes_with_30 = "06" %>
          <%    fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour + 1 %>
          <%  elsif (39 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 44)   %>
          <%    fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour + 1 %>
          <%    minutes = "42" %>
          <%    minutes_with_30 = "12" %>
          <%  elsif (45 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 50)   %>
          <%    fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour + 1 %>
          <%    minutes = "48"   %>
          <%    minutes_with_30 = "18" %>
          <%  elsif (51 <= minutes) && (minutes <= 56)   %>
          <%   fin_hour_with_30 =  fin_hour + 1 %>
          <%    minutes = "54"   %>
          <%    minutes_with_30 = "24" %>
          <%  else %>
          <%    minutes = min % 60 %>
          <%  end  %>

          <p> You are off at <strong><%= "#{fin_hour}:#{minutes}" %></strong> PM Without A lunch </p>
          <p> You are off at <strong><%= "#{fin_hour_with_30}:#{minutes_with_30}" %></strong> PM With A 30 minute lunch </p>
          <p> You are off at <strong><%= "#{fin_hour.to_i + 1}:#{minutes}" %></strong> PM With A 1 Hour lunch</p>



            <p>Inserted Hour: <strong><%= timeclock.hour_in %></strong></p>
            <% if timeclock.minutes_in < 10 %>
            <p>Final Minutes: 0<%= timeclock.minutes_in %></p>
            <p>Inserted Minutes 0<%= timeclock.minutes_in %></p>
            <% else %>
            <p>Final Minutes: <%= timeclock.minutes_in %></p>
            <p>Inserted Minutes <%= timeclock.minutes_in %></p>
            <% end %>
            <button class="button"> <%= link_to 'Show', timeclock %></button>
            <button class="button"> <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_timeclock_path(timeclock) %></button>
            <button class="button"> <%= link_to 'Destroy', timeclock, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></button>
    </div>
    <% end %>


<br>

<button class="button"><%= link_to 'New Timeclock', new_timeclock_path %></button>
</div>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Putting it in a view helper as rails_id suggests would be better.

Comment: honestly your code look ugly and it has everything which is against Ruby + Rails

Comment: please review the code I added..ideally it should be like this and you should never ever write those lengthy method on view side. welcome to Rails world